# Edit something in fund item by Mongoid .where directive

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, mongoid

Here is my `Mongoid` query:

```
@items_list = Post.where(_id: params['id'] , owner_id:current_user['_id'])
```

And I return the result as JSON response like this:

```
render json: {:status => true , :line => @items_list}
```

I want to update the post title before returning data to front-end. Update title of post that this query just found, edit it and then render it to front-end.  How can do that?

Comment: What exactly do you want to update in the title? Do you want the update to the title saved to the database or not?

Comment: No, I fetched posts from DB and want to send the result to front-end to show to user. Before sending to front-end, I want to edit the title of the post then send it to front-end. My problem is how can I access and edit values of @items_list ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution

```
@items_list = JSON.parse( @items_list.to_json )
@items_list[0]['title'] = 'NEW: ' + @items_list[0]['title']
render json: {:status => true , :line => @items_list}
```

Comment: No need to parse it. `@items_list.first.title = 'NEW: ' + @items_list.first.title` - it's a list of `Post` objects.